# Detect the angle of an image with no text and rotate the image (Python)

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

[image]
I want to correct the orientation of some images that are either upside down or rotated to the left/right. These images contain seven segment digital numbers, not text. I have tried methods like HoughLines that work for text images, but they failed for my images. I also want to avoid OCR because some of my images are blurry. How can I detect the angle and rotate the image accordingly?

Comment: Are you sure the images doesn't have the orientation in the Metadata? What kind of assumptions can we make for knowing the orientation? Can you add another sample image (more blurry image)? Is it the original JPEG image or a screenshot of the image?

Comment: Hi, I checked the file info and PIL ExifTags for orientation metadata, but none of the images have it. This is how the original image looks like. When i said the image may be  blurry, i meant image may be taking on different lighting conditions, so some of the numbers may not be very clear sometimes. There is no assumptions about the orentation, the only things we know for the all images is, the screen size is always the same, there is number "3" always in the image same location.

Comment: Perhaps feature match on the battery shape.

Answer (score 0):

> there is number "3" always in the image

If consider the way based on this `3`...

- Binalize with `adaptiveThreshold` like way, and extract black regions.
- Remove regions that are clearly not part of a 7seg based on size, shape, aspect ratio, etc. (`minAreaRect` will be useful.)
- From the shape of the region, it seems that if the region is part of a number, it can be judged which part it can be.
  So, you'll be able to do confirmation "if this region is the part of `3`, other 5 parts of the `3` should be at here, and here...".
- When you find `3`, you can estimate the image rotation angle from the result.

---

I can't show how to actually find `3`...
But, when I did `adaptiveThreshold -> findContours` and removed unnecessary regions, Bounding Boxes(results of `minAreaRect`) of the remaining regions becomes like this:

[image]

And... if stretch the length of them (e.g. by 25%) and draw, regions may be linked and becomes to the shape of number.

[image]

(So, if you have the way to find `3` from this, you can resolve the problem?)